# How to fix 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, stack, queue, bad-alloc

I have to read from file 100 task of a different kind in order to do different operation on a Queue, and print on an output file.
But I get "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' "
As Error
I think is something in template declaration.
I tried to declare it in different ways but seems not to work.
If someone can help me I'll be very gratefull.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <fstream>
#include    <string>

#define INPUT_FILE "input.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE "output.txt"
using namespace std;


template <typename T> class Pila
{
private:
bool empty=1;
public:
int lunghezza;
int cima;
T * Tab;
    Pila(int L){
        lunghezza=L;
        Tab= new T[L];
        cima=lunghezza;
    }
    void Push(T L){  
        cima--;
        Tab[cima]=L;
    }

    void Pop(){

        if(!empty)
        cima++;
        if(cima=lunghezza) empty=1;
    }

    bool Empty(){
       if(empty==1) return 1;
       else return 0;
    }

    T top(){
        return Tab[cima];
    }


    void Print(){
        for(int i=lunghezza-1; i>=cima; i--) cout<< Tab[i]<< " ";
    }
};

template <typename V> class Queue
{

public:
    int lunghezza;

    Queue(int l){
        lunghezza=l;
    };
    Pila<V> A= Pila <V>(lunghezza);
    Pila<V> B= Pila <V>(lunghezza);

    void enqueue(V L){ //sposta tutti gli elementi da A a B 
        while(!A.Empty()){ 
            B.Push(A.top());
            A.Pop();
        }

        A.Push(L); //Mette L dentro A

        while(!B.Empty()){   //sposta tutto di nuovo dentro A
            A.Push(B.top());
            B.Pop();
        }
    }


    void dequeue(){
        if(A.Empty()){
            cout<< " Coda Vuota"<< endl;
        }
        else       
        A.Pop();
    }    

    void Stampa(){
            A.Print();
            cout<< endl; 
    }
};

int main(){


    fstream infile, outfile;

    infile.open(INPUT_FILE, fstream::in);
    outfile.open(OUTPUT_FILE, fstream::out);


    int c=0, N,tmp;
    string tipo,operazione;
    while(c<100){
        infile>> tipo;
        infile>> N;
       if(tipo=="int"){
            Queue<int> A(N);
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.dequeue();
                else
                {
                    int elem=stoi(operazione.substr(1));
                    A.enqueue(elem);
                }

            }
            A.Stampa();
        }

        if(tipo=="double"){
            Queue<double> A(N);
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.dequeue();
                else
                {
                    double elem=stod(operazione.substr(1));
                    A.enqueue(elem);
                }

            }
            A.Stampa();
        }


        if(tipo=="bool"){
            Queue<bool> A(N);
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.dequeue();
                else
                {
                    bool elem=stoi(operazione.substr(1));
                    A.enqueue(elem);
                }

            }
            A.Stampa();          
        }

        if(tipo=="char"){
            Queue<char> A(N);
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.dequeue();
                else
                {
                    char elem=(char)(operazione[1]);
                    A.enqueue(elem);
                }

            }
           A.Stampa();           
        }


        c++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Get used to use English only identifiers in code. You *will* share code with people not knowing Italian language, and if only here on SO. Knowledge about what variables are used for will help them understanding your code better/faster and you might get better responses faster...

Comment: You're leaking **_a lot_** of memory. I guess it runs out eventually, therefore `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

Comment: This is rather a lot of code to inspect and debug for you. Can you reduce it to a more minimal example? Maybe something that manipulates your Pila and Queue objects directly?

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` means, that memory allocation failed. Maybe you are trying to allocate too much memory?

Comment: Side note: `empty` variable is redundant, you get the same information via `cima == lunghezza`. Try to avoid redundancies, they most often are a source of trouble.

Comment: `if(cima=lunghezza)` – must be `if(cima == lunghezza)`, otherwise you do assignment (i. e. in concrete case, you empty the stack...). And you do not set `empty` to false on pushing (see: redundancies!).

Comment: You have no check for stack being full already in `Pila::Push`. Only allow pushing, if cima is yet > 0!

Comment: I eliminated "empty" changing the function. I also changed the Main in order to understand where's the problem, but same problem as before

Comment: `Pila(int L) { Tab= new T[L]; }` – if you allocate on creation, you need to destroy on destruction, i. e. you need a custom destructor as well. But then consider rules of [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)! Simpler solution: use a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

Comment: Oh, and please: don't do `if(condition) return true; else return false;` – that's bad style, just do `return condition;`. If you use booleans, best just check them without comparisons (`if(empty)`).

Comment: Honestly, your stack implementation (`Pila`) is not suitable to base a queue on. This copying around between those two stacks (`Queue::enqueue`) is inefficient as worse almost couldn't be. How did you get that idea?

Comment: General recommendation: Don't write any output from within any general purpose classes (-> containers -> `Queue`). You impose that on any one using them even if not wanting (not at all or perhaps just in a different language), so she/he is trapped... (`cout << " Coda Vuota" << endl;`)

Comment: I have to implement a template class Queue using only 2 Stacks. My idea was to fill a Stack and empty it into the other Stack

Comment: @GianlucaDiMauro I see, imposed by question/task... Still suggesting some improvement: On enqueuing, only shift all elements to stack B, but not back. Shift them back on dequeuing. This way, you only do shifts when really needed (sparing repeated shifts on subsequent enqueuings).

Comment: `int c=0; while(c<100) { /* ... */ c++; }` is better written as `for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: About how much data in the files are we talking? You are running your loop 100 times, together with quite a large N and considering the memory leak (see my comment about rule of three/five and smart pointers), that might be an issue.

Comment: Side note: Those `if(tipo == "XYZ") { }` all share the same code apart from minimal details. you could write a template function accepting two template parameters: type of queue and function to call to convert input. Then you'd call this function appropriately parametrised and would spare all this duplicated code...

Comment: I have to read 100 input line from file; Each line can have up to 10000 elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is in your initialization.

```
int lunghezza;

Queue(int l){
    lunghezza=l;
};
Pila<V> A= Pila <V>(lunghezza);
Pila<V> B= Pila <V>(lunghezza);
```

`A` and `B` will be initialized with the value of `lunghezza` which is not yet initialized. This way you can get a very high value that allocate lots of memory.

A better implementation of this part is to use initializers

```
int lunghezza;

Queue(int l) : lunghezza(l), A(l), B(l)
{
}

Pila<V> A;
Pila<V> B;
```

You second problem is in `Pila` class.

```
Pila(int L){
    lunghezza=L;
    Tab= new T[L];
    cima=lunghezza;
}
```

In this code, Tab is never disallocated so you will leak (loose) the allocated memory when your object will be destroyed. You must call `delete[] Tab;` in your destructor.

You can also use STL classes such as `std::list` or `std::vector` to replace your class `Pila`.